# Is it possible to prevent being ranked for nonsensical, detrimental keywords in Google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, ranking

A (somehow) related question was posted 4 years ago, but couldn't get any answer at the time. So I hope some experts have come up with a solution since then. Our website ranks for the wrong keywords. By "wrong" I don't just mean "cake" for "waffles", but crappy keywords that are totally unrelated (and detrimental). Our rankings are still relatively low regarding the topic we are the only experts on (yes, it can exist, and it is the case, here). The website is 5 years old and recognized as a reference (we've been - genuinely, we've never asked or paid for anything! - added by journalists in their articles, in Wikipedia entries, etc.).

But Google has never fixed the bad keyword thing and STILL ranks us on those crappy-crazy keywords you won't find anywhere on the site. So this doesn't add up at all and can only indicate negative SEO practices against us. Problem is: we can't figure out how to "disavow" those keywords, so that we stop being ranked for them. Just imagine a website dealing with microsurgery and ranking on "dual flush toilet". Of course it sounds hilarious, until you experience it yourself!

Comment: Are you sure the site has not been hacked?  Have you looked at its backlinks?